# compilation error involving struct

Tags: c, compilation

I really dislike asking about compilation errors here, but this one has been really bugging me.

I have the following code:

```
struct rtModel_capacitor {
  ....
};
extern rtModel_capacitor *const capacitor_rtM;
```

This gives the error (for the last line):

```
expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
```

Why won't this compile?

Comment: `extern struct rtModel_capacitor *const capacitor_rtM;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different ways to resolve the problem:

```
struct rtModel_capacitor {
  ....
};
extern struct rtModel_capacitor *const capacitor_rtM;
```

or

```
struct rtModel_capacitor {
  ....
};
typedef struct rtModel_capacitor rtModel_capacitor;
extern rtModel_capacitor *const capacitor_rtM;
```

or

```
typedef struct {
  ....
}rtModel_capacitor;
extern rtModel_capacitor *const capacitor_rtM;
```

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Looks like you're writing in a newer style than your compiler supports. Have you checked your compiler flags to see if you can select different dialects and perhaps compile a more recent syntax? That code should not be a problem in C99 and beyond. I tried using gcc 4.8.4, and your code compiled fine, as it should.